# Shell export not working

Tags: perl, shell, unix

There is a shell program. The shell program:

1. Contains a command (which is another shell program) which runs and prints three values.
2. The three values are then exported.
3. At last a Perl file is executed (this uses exported values).

All this happens in a shell file.

My problem is export does not happen in the Perl file.  What could be the problem?

Comment: You'll have to give us more to go on than that. Can you post the shell script, at least? And possibly the perl script too?

Comment: This qwuestion deserves the shortest possible answer: Anything. Seriously, do you think we are magicians? BTW, some of us are indeed and could tell you, that your concept is likely not to work.

Comment: can we have the script to illustrate the problem? you don't even say which shell this is.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't give us much to go on, but the script below meets the criteria in the question.  It produces the answer 6.  The command in (1) is `echo` and it prints three values.  The command in (2) is the `export` line, obviously.  The command in (3) is the `perl` command, which adds the values in the environment variables a, b and c followed by a newline.

```
 set -- $(echo a=1 b=2 c=3)
 export $1 $2 $3
 perl -e 'print $ENV{a} + $ENV{b} + $ENV{c}, "\n"'
```

There are a myriad possible variations on it; I'd not claim this is a good solution to your problem.  But it meets the criteria laid down.  You'd do better, though, to show your own attempt to solve the problem, and seek assistance in improving it.

Also, as you will see if you run the script, `export` does work.  If it wasn't working in your script, it must mean you were misusing it.  However, since you didn't show us your code, we cannot help you fix the problem in your code.  It is a poor craftsman who blames his tools for his own shortcomings.  And it is sign of a tyro to claim that something which millions of people use successfully every day "doesn't work".  There is a small chance that you have found a way in which it is broken - but the chance is vanishingly small and would have to be exemplified in detail.

Comment: Using my crystal ball, I suspect rathika's error is thinking that $a could be used instead of $ENV{a} in the perl script.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments it's a bit hard to diagnose with this amount of info, but you wouldn't have to export anything if you made the perl script read the values from the standard input instead of from the environment. Then your "shell program" would just be

```
command_from_step_1 | perl_script_from_step_3
```

with a pipe character in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script with the shell's '-x' option to see what's happening.